# Java Drawing Shape with "*"

Tags: java

I am very new to programming and am just trying to see if there are simpler ways to create the shape below.

I got the shape by using `System.out.println()` multiple times, but again am just trying to see if there are more concise ways to create this. I got the shape with this code, but if anyone has any other ways to do so please let me know!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("******");
    System.out.println(" *    *");
    System.out.println("  *    *");
    System.out.println("   ******");
    System.out.println("  *    *");
    System.out.println(" *    *");
    System.out.println("******");
    System.out.println(" *    *");
    System.out.println("  *    *");
    System.out.println("   ******");
}
```

Comment: You can draw using Spring. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578835/how-do-i-draw-various-shapes-in-java-which-library-should-i-use Please refer to this.

Comment: Why don't give a simple example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I draw various shapes in Java ? Which library should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578835/how-do-i-draw-various-shapes-in-java-which-library-should-i-use)

Comment: @ArchitGoyal No. That is graphics libraries, not printing on console

Comment: I agree. Program to create shapes and show them on console[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657121/program-to-create-shapes-and-show-them-on-console] This will help.

Comment: You can use loops and utility methods. It depends on what you want to learn next.

Comment: You have two repeating things here. The `******` and the `*    *`. The only thing that changes is with how much spaces you prepend. So create two methods, one for the all-star thing and one for the other. Let both accept a number for how much spaces it should prepend. Then creating the sequence already looks way clearer and you could also easily adjust how long it should be.

Answer (score 3):

So I think you want this in the output console

```
******
 *    *
  *    *
   ******
  *    *
 *    *
******
 *    *
  *    *
   ******
```

So why don't make an static function and a for for outputing in the console:

```
public static void main(String[]args) 
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int howManyTimes = scan.nextInt();

    for(int i=0;i<howManyTimes;i++)
    {
        outPut();
    }
    System.out.println("******"); // For always closing the Graph
}

public static void outPut()
    {
        System.out.println("******");
        System.out.println(" *    *");
        System.out.println("  *    *");
        System.out.println("   ******");
        System.out.println("  *    *");
        System.out.println(" *    *");
    }
```

Input 
5

OutPut:

```
******
 *    *
  *    *
   ******
  *    *
 *    *
******
 *    *
  *    *
   ******
  *    *
 *    *
******
 *    *
  *    *
   ******
  *    *
 *    *
******
 *    *
  *    *
   ******
  *    *
 *    *
******
 *    *
  *    *
   ******
  *    *
 *    *
******
```

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

Two things do repeat here:

```
******
*    *
```

The rest of the code only adjusts with how much **spaces** you **prefix the pattern** and the overall logic of **moving the pattern** to the right or back to the left.

---

### Base

So, let's first create two methods and a small helper method:

```
private static String constructPrefix(int length) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private static void printDelimiter(int indent) {
    System.out.println(constructPrefix(indent) + "******");
}

private static void printPart(int indent) {
    System.out.println(constructPrefix(indent) + "*    *");
}
```

---

### Movement

Next we will create a helper method that moves the sequence to the right and one to move it to the left:

```
private static void printSequenceToRight(int indentRight) {
    // Start with an indent of one, include the end
    for (int i = 0; i <= indentRight; i++) {
        printPart(i);
    }
}

private static void printSequenceToLeft(int indentRight) {
    // Start with right end, include one
    for (int i = indentRight; i >= 1; i--) {
        printPart(i);
    }
}
```

---

### Sequence

Now we need a method that prints one part of the sequence. Let's define that a part always starts with the delimiter and ends without delimiter.

```
private static void printSequence(int indent) {
    printDelimiter(0);
    printSequenceToRight(indent - 1);
    printDelimiter(indent);
    printSequenceToLeft(indent - 1);
}
```

Finally all we need is a method that prints a full sequence, i.e. that repeats a sequence (and appends the final delimiter):

```
public static void printFullSequence(int amount, int indent) {
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        printSequence(indent);
    }
    printDelimiter(0);
}
```

---

### Usage

Usage is simple, a call could look like:

```
printFullSequence(5, 2);
```

Output is:

```
******
 *    *
  *    *
   ******
  *    *
 *    *
******
 *    *
  *    *
   ******
  *    *
 *    *
******
 *    *
  *    *
   ******
  *    *
 *    *
******
 *    *
  *    *
   ******
  *    *
 *    *
******
 *    *
  *    *
   ******
  *    *
 *    *
******
```

The cool thing is, it's fully dynamic. You could also call it like

```
printFullSequence(1, 6);
```

Which outputs:

```
******
 *    *
  *    *
   *    *
    *    *
     *    *
      *    *
       ******
      *    *
     *    *
    *    *
   *    *
  *    *
 *    *
******
```